# Question about IIS output in Pyomo, Gurobipy

Tags: optimization, python, gurobi, pyomo, irreducible-infeasible-subset

These days I try to build a Gurobipy optimization model by Pyomo and I met a problem about outputing IIS file.
I use

```
opt = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python")
option = {"MIPGAP":0.001, "TimeLimit":300}
obj = ...
for k, v in option.items():
  opt.options[k] = v
result = opt.solve(model, warmstart=True, tee=True, options_string="ResultFile=iis_{}.ilp".format("model"))
```

When model comes IIS, I find that the variables in IIS's constrains have no variable name or index I coded but some numeric serial number only like

```
x95729: -x36195 - 1.71 x40465 = 0
```

I can't figure out which constraint it is. Then I try to use

```
log_infeasiable_constraints(model, log_expression=True, log_variables=True)
```

to find out which constraints and variables issue the IIS, and I get a lot of constraints, the number of them far exceeds the number of constraints I got through the last approach (maybe I would have gotten a few with the last approach, whereas with log_infeasiable I would have gotten dozens) And I find that some variables' value in constraints is "None".

Are there some solutions that could calculate the minimum IIS constraints with variables' names and indexes? And where do these variables that turn into None values come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `symbolic_solver_labels=True` option to your call to `solve`:

```
result = opt.solve(model, warmstart=True, tee=True, symbolic_solver_labels=True, options_string="ResultFile=iis_{}.ilp".format("model"))
```

This option should preserve the variable names that you set when the model gets passed to the solver.

Comment: thx for help.Yet when I add the symbolic_solver_labels=True option to my solver, it raise ValueError says it is a unrecognized keyword.My gurobi is 9.0.3, is this a problem caused by version differences?

Comment: There are a few different Pyomo interfaces to Gurobi so I suspect the one you're using doesn't support the option I mentioned. Another thing you could try is the `pyomo.contrib.iis` extension which you can find here: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/pyomo/contrib/iis/iis.py

Comment: it's works! Thx for your help again!